# Functional Limits and Continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

so here is a problem I have been working on:

Assume g is defined and continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

If $g(x_0) > 0$ for a single point  $x_0  \in \mathbb{R}$, then $g(x)$ is in fact strictly positive for uncountably many points.

So far I've come up with the following:
(I've already shown there exists a bijective function between any interval (a, b), a < b, and R so I first take that for granted.) Since this is true, any interval (a, b) contains uncountably many points. Thus, the interval (0, g(x0)) contains uncountably many points.

Now, here is my issue: how does one use continuity to show that g(x) must contain this interval rigorously? Intuitively, this conclusion seems obvious.

Comment: it's not truue that $]0,g(x_0)[ \subset g(\Bbb R)$. Take $g(x) =1$

Comment: Let $I := (\frac{g(x_0)}2,\frac 3 2g(x_0))$ and consider $g^{-1}(I)$. What do you know about it?

Comment: @Tryss I don't believe that can be a suitable value for g(x) since g(x) is supposed to be positive only at x0. Moreover, any function g > 0 would makes this proof a one-liner.

Comment: @EthanZell : If g(x) is positive only at one point, then by hypothesis it cannot be strictly positive for uncountably many points.... I think what is asked is "if there exist a point where g is strictly positive, there exist uncountably many points where g is strictly positive"

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by what do I know about g-1(I). I know that it corresponds to an interval in the co-domain, part of which must be in the domain and the other part not necessarily.

Comment: @Tryss I see what you're saying now. I'll need some time to ruminate on this though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible proof is this one :

Let $\epsilon = \frac{g(x_0)}{2}$, then by continuity, there exist $\delta > 0$ such that $\forall x\in ]x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta[, 0<g(x_0)-\epsilon \leq g(x) \leq g(x_0)+\epsilon$

So $\forall x\in ]x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta[, g(x >0)$ and as there are uncountably points in this interval, we have the resultat

Comment: Ah, I see. This looks more like the epsilon neighborhood characterization of continuity. I think I just found this argument hard to construct since we are not actually choosing a specific delta. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$g$ continuous and $g(x_0)>0$ gives us :

It exists a real E so that [ $g(x_0 - E) , g(x_0+E)$ ] $> 0$

Which means there is an infinite number of points $x$ that have $g(x)>0$